# How to change title of NSPanel at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Maybe I'm missing something really simple here (I hope so), but is there a trick to changing the title of an NSPanel at runtime? The obvious [panel setTitle:@"New title"] doesn't seem to be working.

I'm trying to display a regular panel which contains a WebView, and I want to the title of the panel to reflect the title of the HTML content.

I subclassed NSWindowController and called initWithWindowNibName. I changed the class in the nib from NSWindow to NSPanel, and everything seems to be working okay. In my window controller, I did this:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [[self window] setTitle:@"My New Title"];
}
```

(I will actually be setting the title in a webView:didReceiveTitle:forFrame delegate, but this is simpler to show).

I verified that the code is getting called, and there are no errors reported, but the title never changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the nib file that contains the panel, make sure that the File’s Owner’s class has been set to your NSWindowController subclass and that the `window` outlet from File’s Owner has been connected to the panel. Otherwise, the window controller won’t know which window it should be managing and `[self window]` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the title, but you're not telling the window to display itself again.

Comment: There's no need to do any such thing. Simply sending the window a `setTitle:` message is enough to change its title. I tested this with both an NSWindow and an NSPanel.